# Identificar um caractere em uma string e fazer validações

Tags: string, validação, caracteres

Pessoal estou com um problema para resolver:

Tenho um uma string que é um Nome  SYLVIA

Eu preciso fazer uma busca nessa string achar a letra Y e depois verificar se após a letra Y a próxima letra é Vogal ou Consoante.

No caso do nome SYLVIA a próxima letra é L então retorna Consoante.

Alguém sabe montar esse algoritmo ai?

Segue o código feito até agora:

```php
$tam =strlen($string[0]);

// VERIFICO SE EXISTE A LETRA Y NA PALAVRA

$substring2 = "Y";
$posicaoy =strpos($str1,$substring2);

$str = $primeironome;
$search = 'Y';

if(preg_match("/{$search}/i", $str)) {
    echo 'A palavra Y existe na string!';
    echo "<br />";

    // SEPARA A PALVRA APÓS A LETRA Y PARA VALIDAR

$UID = $primeironome;
$stringParts = explode("Y", $UID);
$firstPart  = $stringParts[0]; 
$secondPart = $stringParts[1]; 

echo "PRIMEIRO PARTE: ". $firstPart;
echo "<br>";
echo "SEGUNDA PARTE: ". $secondPart;
echo "<br>";

$extrair=$secondPart;
$prisn = substr($extrair,0,1);
echo "LETRA APÓS O Y: ". $prisn;
echo "<br>";

if (empty($prisn)) {
    /* String is empty */
    echo "<br>";
    echo "LETRA APÓS O Y é VAZIA: ". $prisn;
    echo "<br>";

} else {
    /* vazio */
}

// VERIFICAR SE É VOGAL OU CONSOANTE

$palavra=$prisn;
if($palavra{0}=="A" or $palavra{0}=="E" or $palavra{0}=="I" or $palavra{0}=="O" or$palavra{0}=="U"){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "depois do Y é uma vogal";
    echo "<br>";
    
}else{
echo "<br>";
echo "depois do Y é uma consoante";
echo "<br>";

}
} else  {

    echo 'A palavra  Y não existe na string!';
    echo "<br />";

}
// FINAL DA VALIDAÇÃO


// resultado do algoritmo
```

PRIMEIRO NOME: SYLVIA

VOGAIS: A palavra Y existe na string!
PRIMEIRO PARTE: S
SEGUNDA PARTE: LVIA
LETRA APÓS O Y: L

depois do Y é uma consoante

Estou achando muito extenso o código tem alguma forma melhor de simplificar?

Woss agora eu preciso simplificar a validação se após y  letra é uma vogal ou consoante:

Esse código aqui:

```php
$palavra=$prisn;
if($palavra{0}=="A" or $palavra{0}=="E" or $palavra{0}=="I" or $palavra{0}=="O" or$palavra{0}=="U"){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "depois do Y é uma vogal";
    echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "depois do Y é uma consoante";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Pronto agora só falta dá uma enxugada nesse código abaixo:

```
for($b=0; $b<$len; $b++)
{

$str1 =$string[0];
$alpha2  = $str1[$b];
$numero8 = $ar[$alpha2];


if ($b == $tam){    
    break;
}

if ($numero8 == 1) {
    $numero8 = A;   
  
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>". $numero8 ."</span>";
}

if ($numero8 == 5) {
    $numero8 = E;   
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'> - ". $numero8 ."</span>";
}

if ($numero8 == 9) {
    $numero8 = I;    
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'> - ". $numero8 ."</span>";
}

if ($numero8 == 6) {
    $numero8 = O;    
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'> - ". $numero8 ."</span>";
}

if ($numero8 == 3) {
    $numero8 = U;    
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'> - ". $numero8 ."</span>";
}



if ($numero8 == 7) {    
    $numero8 = Y;
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'> - ". $numero8 ."</span>";
}

}
```

Comment: Por que usou o `strpos`, uma expressão regular e o `explode` tudo no mesmo código para fazerem, ao que parece, a mesma coisa?

Comment: usei a expressão explode para separa a palavra e pegar a próxima letra após o Y. a a expressão strpos faz isso também?

Comment: https://ideone.com/CmVqFJ

Comment: vou testar aqui meu amigo e te retorno. Obrigado

Comment: Woss simplificou muito obrigado meu amigo vou ver o resto do código e posto aqui e ver o que pode ser simplificado a mais.

Comment: Para a parte final, vc tem que ver primeiro se é uma letra. Se for, aí vê se é vogal (se não for, é consoante), assim: https://ideone.com/Uam9aK - A resposta abaixo não faz a primeira verificação, então se o caractere for um dígito, sinal de pontuação, espaço, etc, ela diz que é consoante (só tem que ver se no seu caso esses caracteres aparecem na sua string - se não aparecem, aí não precisaria verificar se é letra)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O código abaixo faz essa avaliação através da busca pela posição da letra desejada na palavra.

Caso encontre, ele usa uma Expressão Regular para identificar a letra seguinte e a avalia:

```php
function avaliaProxima($palavra, $letra){
    //caso a palavra não tenha a letra, já retorna 
    if(strpos($palavra, $letra) === false){
        return "A palavra '$palavra' não tem a letra '$letra'.";
    }
    //caso a letra seja a última, retorna e informa
    if(strpos($palavra, $letra) == strlen($palavra) -1){
        return "A letra '$letra' é a última letra da palavra '$palavra', portanto, não tem nada após ela.";
    }
    //usa uma ER para pegar a próxima letra que exite após a letra desejada.
    $er = "/[$letra](\w)/";
    preg_match($er, $palavra, $resultados);
    $proxima = $resultados[1]; //aqui está a próxima letra
    $vogais = 'AEIOU'; //as vogais
    $resultado = "consoante"; //já marca como consoante
    if(strpos(strtoupper($vogais), $proxima) !== false){
        $resultado = "vogal"; //exceto se econtrar dentro das vogais
    }
    return "Encontrei '$proxima' após a letra '$letra' na palavra '$palavra' e ela é uma $resultado.";
}

echo avaliaProxima("SYLVIA", "Y");
```

O resultado desse código é:

> Encontrei 'L' após a letra 'Y' na palavra 'SYLVIA' e ela é uma consoante.

Lembre-se que no caso de acentuação, será necessário acrescentar a todas essas possibilidades na variável `$vogais`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo ajudou muito aqui.

Comment: Disponha, solicito que aceite a resposta caso julgue adequada.